# For positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$ of order $n$, if $A \geq B$ then $\det(A+B) \geq \det(A) + n \det(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What's the shortest way to answer the following question?

> Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices of order $n$ and $A\ge B$, then $\det(A+B) \ge \det(A) + n\det(B)$.

All I can do is a volume argument about $\det(A+B) \geq \det(A) + \det(B)$, but the $n$ in there gives me problems.

Comment: $|A| = \det A$ ?

Comment: Yes, $|A| = \det \ A$

Comment: Better yet, you can show that $\det\left(A+B\right) \geq \det A + \left(2^n-1\right)\det B$. Here is the idea: Every principal minor of $A$ is $\geq$ to the corresponding principal minor of $B$ (because $A \geq B$ yields the analogous inequality between the principal submatrices of $A$ and $B$). But the number $\det\left(A+B\right) - \det A$ can be written as a sum of terms of the form "proper principal minor of $A$ times complementary principal minor of $B$", where "proper" means "not the whole $\det A$" (because we have subtracted $\det A$). In this ...

Comment: ... sum, we can replace each proper principal minor of $A$ by the respective principal minor of $B$ (since, as we have just seen, the former is $\geq$ to the latter, whereas its cofactor is nonnegative); the resulting sum will then be $\det\left(B+B\right) - \det B$. Hence, we have shown that $\det\left(A+B\right) - \det A \geq \det\left(B+B\right) - \det B = \left(2^n-1\right) \det B$, qed. Let me know if you want more details.

Answer (score 1):

Hint prove it for $B=I_n$ ($tr(I_n)=n$)

---

Perhaps the hint was not enough so I will try to complete with an answer

- First case $B = I_n$, let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigen values of $A$, then the eigen values of $A+I_n$ are $\lambda_1 + 1, \ldots, \lambda_n+1$ so $$\det(A+I) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+ \lambda_i\right) \ge \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_i + \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \ge \det(A) + \text{tr}(A) \ge \det(A) + \text{tr}(I_n) = \det(A) + n\det(I_n)$$
- If $B$ is not invertible the inequality is trivial. Otherwise, $B^{-\frac12}A B^{-\frac12}\ge I_n$ applying the above result we have $$\det(B^{-\frac12}A B^{-\frac12} + I_n) \ge \det(B^{-\frac12}A B^{-\frac12}) + n$$ now you just have to multiply by the $\det(B)$

Comment: I don't think $B^{-1}A \geq I_n $ is true in general  (if $A,B $ do not commute). What is true is $B^{-1/2}A B^{-1/2}\geq I_n $, and then the rest of your argument should go through.

Comment: You are right @PhoemueX

Comment: Your argument, too, yields the stronger inequality $\det\left(A+B\right) \geq \det A + \left(2^n-1\right)\det B$.

Comment: Why inequality is trivial if $B$ is not invertible (btw, it can't be not invertible, because it is positive definite)? Is there a trivial proof showing $\det(A+B) \geq \det(A)$?